# Should I add additional Filters in TSQL in a SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to pull data from the source system based on a specific time window (from `StartDate` to `EndDate`). The below query shows 3 tables joined. Should i give date window condition for only the main table or the referenced tables as well?

```
SELECT T1.Col1
       ,T1.Col2
       ,T1.Col3
       ,T2.Col1
       ,T2.Col2
       ,T3.Col1
       ,T3.Col2
       ,T3.Col3
    FROM MainTable T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable1 T2
        ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable2 T3
        ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
    WHERE T1.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
            -- Any record in this table before/after the date window would affect?
        AND T2.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate   
            -- Any record in this table before/after the date window would affect?
        AND T3.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Comment: Can i ignore the conditions for T2 and T3 tables?

Comment: This will depend on the data - it is possible that the referenced tables don't get updated at the same interval as your main table, in which case, no you shouldn't include filters, as long as there are good indexes on `MainTable.ModifiedDateTime` and on the foreign keys. Also note that if any of the joins fail, the `WHERE T2.xxx and T3.xxx's` will effectively eliminate all rows since `T2.x / T3.x` will be null (i.e. the nett result being the same effect as an `INNER JOIN`).

Comment: Referenced tables are not getting updated at the same time. The first condition gives the required count only. Whereas the remaining two conditions eliminates rows. That means i should only use the first condition? Right Stu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your data integrity. If your foreign keys will produce only desired rows once primary table if filtered you do not need additional conditions.

Best thing is to test all the possibilities by running counts with different options.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM MainTable T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable1 T2
        ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable2 T3
        ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
    WHERE T1.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM MainTable T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable1 T2
        ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable2 T3
        ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
    WHERE T1.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        AND T2.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        AND T3.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Comment: Referenced tables are not getting updated at the same time. The first condition gives the required count only. Whereas the remaining two conditions eliminates rows. That means i should only use the first condition?

Comment: Use what ever condition gives you the required count. If first one gives you want you need, than remove the last two. Without seeing tables and sample data it is impossible to know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the referenced tables do not get updated at the same interval as your main table, then no, you definitely should **NOT** include filters on `T2` and `T3`.

If the reason why these are included is for performance reasons, it probably means that you are missing an index on `MainTable.ModifiedDateTime`. Also, ensure that the join keys `T1.Col1`, `T2.Col1` and `T3.Col1` are indexed.

Also note that if any of the joins fail (i.e. if there IS no row in `T2` or `T3` with the value `Col1`), that the `WHERE T2.xxx and T3.xxx` predicates will effectively eliminate all rows since T2.x / T3.x will be null. If you wish to reproduce this effect in the query without the `T2 / T3` col filters, then you should switch the joins to `T2` / `T3` to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3, T2.Col1, T2.Col2, T3.Col1, T3.Col2, T3.Col3
    FROM MainTable T1
    INNER JOIN ReferenceTable1 T2
        ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
    INNER JOIN ReferenceTable2 T3
        ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
    WHERE T1.ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;
```